# How to Set Dynamically Table name in DynamoDb

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Unity 2019 and have a dynamically set a table name in DynamoDB.

```
[DynamoDBTable("mydynamodbtablename")]
public class HighLevelTableExample : DynamoDbBaseExample
{
    public string S_tablefieldset;
    ....
}
```

I found the code for replace the  dynamic table

```
public static DynamoDBOperationConfig GetDynamoDbOperationConfig(string dynamoDbTable)
{
   var config = new DynamoDBOperationConfig
   {
        //    OverrideTableName =
        OverrideTableName = dynamoDbTable
   };

   return config;
}
```

When I used it

```cs
  [DynamoDBTable(
  HighLevelTableExample.GetDynamoDbOperationConfig(S_tablefieldset))]
```

It shows the error.

```
error CS0103: The name 'S_tablefieldset' does not exist in the current context
```

How to call the above static function in unity C#?

Comment: What’s the error ?

Comment: error CS0103: The name 'S_tablefieldset' does not exist in the current context.. I have edited and updated. So how to call it..

Answer (score 0):

C# limits what can be invoked inside an Attribute like the attribute `DynamoDBTable`.  It's basically limited to referencing constants, string literals, enums as well as a few built in functions like `typeof` or `nameof`.

Invoking a method (ie `HighLevelTableExample.GetDynamoDbOperationConfig`) isn't supported by the languages.  And you certainly can't access an **instance** member (`S_tablefieldset`) in the static context of an Attribute; that's why you're getting an exception.

To your goal of using DynamoDB, this blog explains the strategy for using Dynamic Table names: https://enlear.academy/dynamic-table-name-in-dynamodb-using-c-771dc3a5993.

It's necessary to generate a `DynamoDBOperationConfig`, as you're doing in `GetDynamoDbOperationConfig()`, and then pass that to `AmazonDynamoDBClient`:

```cs
var tableName = "mydynamodbtablename";  /*TODO: Dynamically determine table name*/

var highLevelTableConfig = GetDynamoDbOperationConfig(tableName);

var highLevelTableClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(highLevelTableConfig);
```